# Access to the path is denied in C# azure storage download

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am getting access to the path is denied exception while downloading file from azure storage below is code snippet.

```
string path = @"c:\TEMP";

// Retrieve storage account from connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CloudStorageString"]);
// Create the blob client.
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
// Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
// Retrieve reference to a blob named "photo1.jpg".
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("167_PostP45_temp.png");

// Save blob contents to a file.
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running as administrator?

Comment: @Donal, You meant for connecting to visual studio right? If so I am trying run as admin.. but still have issue..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are creating a file on the root of `C:` called `TEMP` with no extension. The root of `C:` is a protected location and can not be written to by non administrative programs.

The other thing that can give you this exception is if you try to call `File.OpenWrite` on a directory, which I think is the more likely thing that is happening to you.

If you are trying to save to the folder `C:\TEMP` you must add the filename on to the path you are opening.

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(path, "167_PostP45_temp.png"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

This also assumes the folder `C:\TEMP` already exists. If you want to use the user's actual temp folder use `Path.GetTempPath()` to get it

```
using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "167_PostP45_temp.png")))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: @Raj if the issue is fixed you should mark an answer accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the question

Comment: the same issue is occurring after publishing the changes on azure. Is their any thing else needs to be done after publishing the solution.

Comment: @Raj likely the directory you are trying to use does not exist. You can use `Directory.CreateDirectory(path);` to create the folder if it does not exist (The user running the program must have rights to create the directory or it will fail)

Comment: I am trying to create folder as well but still getting the same exception while creating the simple folder as well i.e access to path is denied, Is their any settings to be done from azure dashboard to create folder??

Comment: @Raj I am confused, are you trying to create a folder on Azure or are you trying to create a folder on the machine running the program to save the file you got from azure?

Comment: I want to create folder on the machine running the program to save file from azure.

Comment: Honestly, your problem has nothing to do with Azure and are just basic C# skills dealing with files. Take Azure out of the problem, make a new [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) program that re-creates the problem and ask a new question with that.

Comment: I tried to create simple folder on page load using Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\TestLoad"); it is working fine on local, once I deployed it on server, it is showing access denied error..

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems. First, as Guarav Mantri observed, you need to open the file for writing, not the directory. Second, you should use use System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() to retrieve the temporary directory, giving:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + "\\167_PostP45_temp.png"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following code:

```
using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(path + "\\167_PostP45_temp.png"))
{
    blockBlob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: The same issue is occurring after publishing the changes on azure. Is their any thing else needs to be done after publishing the solution