# How to download files from Azure BLOB storage from ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-blob-storage

[image]

I have the ability to download files from my Azure Blob storage from a web application.

Once I get my Azure Blob storage list back, it's not downloaded.

Error entering download blob.

I would appreciate it if you could look at my code and let me know what the problem is.

```
public string DownloadBlob()
    {
        CloudBlobContainer container = GetCloudBlobContainer();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myBlob");
        using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\BlobTest"))
        {
            blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
        }
        return "success!";
    }
```

Comment: can you share error message or error code

Comment: 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException :'C : \ BlobTest '경로에 대한 액세스가 거부되었습니다. error message

Comment: Your code above will download the file on the web server and not on the client machine. The error clearly indicates that you don't have permission to write on C:\.

Comment: You have successfully added the IU privilege to the file. However, the same error occurs.

Comment: An UnauthorizedAccessException means one of 4 things:

The caller does not have the required permission.
The file is an executable file that is in use.
Path is a directory.
Path specified a read-only file.

Comment: Have a look at this SO thread which talks about a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487796/access-to-the-path-is-denied-in-c-sharp-azure-storage-download

Answer (score 4):

I have tested your code and it works in my MVC web application as below.

```
    public ActionResult Download()
    {

        ContentResult contentResult = new ContentResult();
        contentResult.Content = DownloadBlob();
        return contentResult;
    }

    public static string DownloadBlob()
    {
        try
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=leeliublob;AccountKey=O7xB6ebGq8e86XQSy2vkvSi/x/e9l9FhLqayXcbz1R+E0mIcJ5Wjkly1DsQPYY5dF2JrAVHtBozbJo29ZrrGJA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net");
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("4.PNG");
            using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Test\BlobTest.PNG"))
            {
                blob.DownloadToStream(fileStream);
            }
            return "success!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.StackTrace;
        }


    }
```

I think this is the problem about the permission of your MVC application.

Your MVC application may use a virtual account of IIS as below, it may have no access to your C disk.
[image]

To solve this problem, here is two ways:

1. Please try to download to other disk like "E" or "D".
2. Please add the user group "Authenticated Users" to that file or folder like below.

[image]

**Update:**

I have reproduced your problem as below:

[image]

We need to create a folder under root directory of C disk as below, because your web application doesn't have the permission to the root directory of C disk:

[image]

Comment: Errors still appear.

Comment: Do you know any other way to save files from my Azure Blob storage to my C drive?

Comment: @LeeLiu, thank you for answering. Do mind that at StackOverflow we prefer you post code as text instead of images.

Comment: @PeterBons Ok, thank you for reminding me, i will modify it.

Comment: @김세림 If the issue was resolved, you can mark the helpful post as answer to help other community members find the helpful information quickly.

Comment: blob.DownloadToStream (fileStream);
What is the error here?

Comment: @김세림 There is no error at [blob.DownloadToStream (fileStream)]. The error is at [var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\BlobTest.PNG")].  we need to modify it like: [var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Test\BlobTest.PNG")]