# Access to the path is denied in C# google cloud storage download

Tags: c#, .net-5, google-cloud-storage

I am working on downloading a csv file from the Google Cloud Storage using C# .NetCore 5. However, got the error: **Access to the path** '/var/folders/r5/p_g28ppd4fj2vsn6hrkcrz1w0000gp/T/' **is denied**. The code I referred is from [the official google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-csharp) and I did a little bit change:

```
public class DownloadFileFromGCS
{
    private readonly string bucketName;
    private readonly string fileName;
    private readonly string localPath;

    public DownloadFileFromGCS(
        string bucketName,
        string fileName,
        string localPath
    )
    {
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.localPath = localPath;
    }

    public void DownloadFile()
    {
        var storage = StorageClient.Create();
        using var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(this.localPath);
        storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, this.fileName, outputFile);
        Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {this.fileName} to {localPath}.");
    }
}
```

However, still got this error when I use it. The issue is similar to this [issue in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487796/access-to-the-path-is-denied-in-c-sharp-azure-storage-download) which I referred to:

```
  var tempPath = Path.GetTempPath();
            await using (File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(tempPath, "my_file.csv")))
            {
                var downloadFile = new DownloadFileFromGCS(
                    "my_bucket",
                    "my_file.csv",
                    tempPath);
                downloadFile.DownloadFile();
            }
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thank you so much in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is because when you define the "localPath" variable you have to include the filename you are going to download.

```
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class StorageExample
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Specify your bucket name and object name
        string bucketName = "your-bucket-name";
        string objectName = "your-object-name";

        // Specify the local path where you want to save the downloaded file
        string downloadLocalPath = "C:\\Users\\LEnriquez\\3D Objects\\Downloads\\downloaded-file.txt";

        try
        {
            // Instantiate a storage client
            var storage = StorageClient.Create();

            // Open a file stream to write the downloaded object
            using (var outputFile = File.OpenWrite(downloadLocalPath))
            {
                // Download the object from the specified bucket and object name
                storage.DownloadObject(bucketName, objectName, outputFile);
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Downloaded {objectName} to {downloadLocalPath}.");
        }
        catch (Google.GoogleApiException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred: {e.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```